# Deutsche Bahn cancelled my train

Tags: cancellations

I received an email that my Cologne to Nuremberg train was cancelled and I should use a link they provided to book another train.  It only takes me to the regular site.  There is no code to input that I am rebooking because of a cancelled train.  I have emailed them twice to the site indicated (somewhere in England) but no response.  Luckily this is not until the end of Oct. so I have a great deal of time.  As I am in the US, I don't want to call as that could be very expensive.  Is there a number to call via Facebook or WhatsApp?  Is there some way to do this rebook now?

Back in Jan. I found upon arrive in Germany that my Frankfurt-Berlin train had been cancelled.  The agent immediately put on another train without a problem and off I went to Berlin.  Could I possibly wait until I am in Cologne and go to an agent the day before schedule travel and rebook?

Comment: Did you make an account with Deutsche Bahn? They are pretty good at managing rebooking and cancellation through bahn.de

Comment: Did you already pay for the train? If yes, were you refunded / was a refund promised?

Comment: Yes, I have an account.  It was paid for but I don't want a refund because to buy a new ticket would cost me more than twice the amount I originally paid.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about seat reservations, you don't have to rebook anything. Your ticket will be valid for the next available train, that brings you to your destination at the initially booked time. Just look at the timetable, what the most convenient connection would be, and use that.

If you have an existing seat reservation and want to rebook that, then you would have to talk to customer support.

Comment: It's not only "the next available train", but any train on that day, independent of the type of ticket (full price or reduced, and train category).

Comment: Thanks.  The responses have been very helpful.

Comment: I asked a follow up question to this answer, linking here in case you have an answer for that: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/177919/73830